# How To Simplify my javascript code for hiding/showing a para

Tags: javascript

I would like to simplify the following code with less script work as i am trying to hide/show a paragraph by button

```
<button onclick="myFunction1()" class="dropbtn">Read more</button>            
   <p id="para1" class="dropdown-content">aasdsadaaaaaaaa fsdgfsdgdg dfdgdfgd11111 ffgfgd dfddf ghfddfd fdfdfhd dfdfdf d</p>

<button onclick="myFunction2()" class="dropbtn">Read more</button>            
   <p id="para2" class="dropdown-content">aasdsadaaaaaaaa fsdgfsdgdg dfdgdfgd11111 ffgfgd dfddf ghfddfd fdfdfhd dfdfdf d</p>

<script>
function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementById("para1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
 }
function myFunction2() {
  var x = document.getElementById("para2");
   if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }  
 }
 </script>
```

as i am not familiar with scripting please help to simplify this i have more function with similar job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the IDs and have a common function that selects the next sibling, which will be the `p` you want to display:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const p = button.nextElementSibling;
    p.style.display = p.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```html
<button>Read more</button>
<p>aasdsadaaaaaaaa fsdgfsdgdg dfdgdfgd11111 ffgfgd dfddf ghfddfd fdfdfhd dfdfdf d</p>

<button>Read more</button>
<p>aasdsadaaaaaaaa fsdgfsdgdg dfdgdfgd11111 ffgfgd dfddf ghfddfd fdfdfhd dfdfdf d</p>
```

You could also use a CSS class that toggles between `block` and `none`, and use `classList.toggle`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    button.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Read more</button>
<p>aasdsadaaaaaaaa fsdgfsdgdg dfdgdfgd11111 ffgfgd dfddf ghfddfd fdfdfhd dfdfdf d</p>

<button>Read more</button>
<p>aasdsadaaaaaaaa fsdgfsdgdg dfdgdfgd11111 ffgfgd dfddf ghfddfd fdfdfhd dfdfdf d</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could make the target to disappear as the parameter, instead of creating 2 functions.

for example:

```html
<button onclick="hideParagraph('para1')" class="dropbtn">Read more</button>            
    <p id="para1" class="dropdown-content">aasdsadaaaaaaaa fsdgfsdgdg dfdgdfgd11111 ffgfgd dfddf ghfddfd fdfdfhd dfdfdf d</p>

    <button onclick="hideParagraph('para2')" class="dropbtn">Read more</button>            
    <p id="para2" class="dropdown-content">aasdsadaaaaaaaa fsdgfsdgdg dfdgdfgd11111 ffgfgd dfddf ghfddfd fdfdfhd dfdfdf d</p>

    <script>
    function hideParagraph(paragraphId) {
      const paragraph = document.getElementById(paragraphId);
      const { display } = paragraph.style;
      paragraph.style.display = display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need Edge or IE compatibility, you can simplify the scripting down to zero with a [`<details>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) (although the Edge team is either [working on it](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/detailssummary/) or has [given up completely](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/12/06/microsoft-edge-making-the-web-better-through-more-open-source-collaboration/)):

```css
/* All this is a (poor) attempt to make the <summary> look
like a <button>. If you were going to style the button
yourself anyway, drop all this. */

summary {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  -moz-appearance: button;
  appearance: button;
  display: inline;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: default;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  font: 13.3333px sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

summary::-webkit-details-marker {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Read more</summary>
  <p>aasdsadaaaaaaaa fsdgfsdgdg dfdgdfgd11111 ffgfgd dfddf ghfddfd fdfdfhd dfdfdf d</p>
</details>

<details>
  <summary>Read more</summary>
  <p>aasdsadaaaaaaaa fsdgfsdgdg dfdgdfgd11111 ffgfgd dfddf ghfddfd fdfdfhd dfdfdf d</p>
</details>
```

The contents of the `<details>` element, excluding the `<summary>`, are hidden until the `<summary>` is clicked. The browser takes care of all the behavior, no JavaScript needed.

Answer (score 0):

To each button add a `data-target` attribute. This is key for this to work.

This attribute points to the element that needs to be toggled on/off.

Notice that each paragraph has the class hidden by default.

```
<button class="dropbtn" data-target="#para1">Read more</button>
<p id="para1" class="dropdown-content hidden">aasdsadaaaaaaaa fsdgfsdgdg dfdgdfgd11111 ffgfgd dfddf ghfddfd fdfdfhd dfdfdf d</p>

<button class="dropbtn" data-target="#para2">Read more</button>
<p id="para2" class="dropdown-content hidden">aasdsadaaaaaaaa fsdgfsdgdg dfdgdfgd11111 ffgfgd dfddf ghfddfd fdfdfhd dfdfdf d</p>
```

Add some styles:

```
<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Finally add logic:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        const { target } = evt;
        if (target.classList.contains('dropbtn')) {
            const paragraphSelector = target.dataset.target;
            const paragraph = document.querySelector(paragraphSelector);
            if (paragraphSelector) {
                paragraph.classList.toggle('hidden');
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```